# iReport issue with lists and whitespace

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, whitespace, ireport

I've had this issue bothering me for quite some time now.

When I leave whitespace underneath a list, the list will push this downwards, instead of overwriting it.
Sometimes while doing so, pushing content onto the next page !

I've tried to illustrate the situation - see attached.

In the first image, the chart at the bottom left has position type "float", hence it's positioned underneath the whitespace.
When I change it to "relative to top", it's positioned at the correct place, but still the whitespace will be present underneath it (between the chart and the footer)

Can this be solved, and how?!
It's a real problem when trying to get a decent layout.

Thanks in advance.
[image: chart1]
[image: chart2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how JasperReports is. You designed the report with whitespace in it, so the report keeps it there.

In many cases (and I suspect that includes this case) you can get what you want by simply making the List component object bigger. In effect will set its minimum size to match the chart to its right. It can stretch further, but it won't force any whitespace to be added into the rendered report.

Comment: +1. I've solved countless problems with reports that turned out to be just this issue. It amazes me how often it comes up. No-one can grok JasperReports until they've understood how it deals with whitespace.

Comment: FINALLY !! Thanks, now I've seen that you can put in the object height (to match the chart on the right) AND the 'item height'. That's what I needed, thanks a lot :)